# Como obtener la ruta del Escritorio del usuario en python?

Tags: python, rutas

Intento guardar un archivo .csv, pero este quisiera crearlo en el escritorio, si agrego mi propia ruta si lo hace pero en otra maquina no.

```
import csv
import os

Data = sys.argv
nombre = Data[1:1] 
Path = os.path

with open(nombre, 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Bitacora.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('Respuesta Servidor', 'Tractor', 'Placas', 'Fecha', 'Codigo'))
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

busque info sobre os.path y ntpath pero no me deja muy en claro la duda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes leer la variable de entrono llamada `USERPROFILE` y construir la ruta hasta el escritorio.

Ejemplo:

```
import os

path_desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
print(path_desktop)
```

Comment: Vaya me funciono a la perfeccion, muchas gracias!! me pondre a leer mas en la documentacion, porque estare usando mucho las variables